# RxJava: Find out if BehaviorSubject was a repeated value or not

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming, rx-java

I'm making an Android interface that shows some data fetched from the network. I want to have it show the latest available data, and to never be empty (unless no data has been fetched at all yet) so I'm using a BehaviorSubject to give subscribers (my UI) the latest available info, while refreshing it in the background to update it.

This works, but due to another requirement in my UI, I now have to know whether or not the published result was gotten fresh from the network or not. (In other words, I need to know if the published result was BehaviorSubject's saved item or not.)

How can I achieve this? If I need to split it up into multiple Observables, that's fine, as long as I'm able to get the caching behavior of BehaviorSubject (getting the last available result) while also being able to tell if the result returned was from the cache or not. A hacky way I can think of to do it would be to check if the timestamp of the response was relatively soon, but that'd be really sloppy and I'd rather figure out a way to do it with RxJava.

Comment: Need to clarify the question ... after the first item is given to BehaviorSubject, subscribers will always receive the cached version first and THEN any new updates. So perhaps is the question whether it's been seen before by anyone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you mentioned in the question, this can be accomplished with multiple Observables. In essence, you have two Observables: "*the fresh response can be observed*", and "*the cached response can be observed*". If something can be "observed", you can express it as an Observable. Let's name the first one `original` and the second `replayed`.

See this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wucecegujo/2/edit?js,console) (JavaScript but the concepts can be directly translated to Java. There isn't a JavaBin as far as I know, for these purposes).

```
var original = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
  .map(function (x) { return {value: x, from: 'original'}; })
  .take(4)
  .publish().refCount();

var replayed = original
  .map(function (x) { return {value: x.value, from: 'replayed'}; })
  .replay(null, 1).refCount();

var merged = Rx.Observable.merge(original, replayed)
  .replay(null, 1).refCount()
  .distinctUntilChanged(function (obj) { return obj.value; });

console.log('subscribe 1st');
merged.subscribe(function (x) { 
  console.log('subscriber1: value ' + x.value + ', from: ' + x.from);
});

setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('    subscribe 2nd');
  merged.subscribe(function (x) {
    console.log('    subscriber2: value ' + x.value + ', from: ' + x.from);
  });
}, 2500);
```

The overall idea here is: annotate the event with a field `from` indicating its origin. If it's `original`, it's a fresh response. If it's `replayed`, it's a cached response. Observable `original` will only emit `from: 'original'` and Observable `replayed` will only emit `from: 'replayed'`. In Java we would require a bit more boilerplate because you need to make a class to represent these annotated events. Otherwise the same operators in RxJS can be found in RxJava.

The original Observable is `publish().refCount()` because we want only one instance of this stream, to be shared with all observers. In fact in RxJS and Rx.NET, `share()` is an alias for `publish().refCount()`.

The replayed Observable is `replay(1).refCount()` because it is also shared just like the original one is, but `replay(1)` gives us the caching behavior.

`merged` Observable contains both original and replayed, and this is what you should expose to all subscribers. Since `replayed` will immediately emit whenever `original` does, we use `distinctUntilChanged` on the event's value to ignore immediate consecutives. The reason we `replay(1).refCount()` **also the merged** is because we want the merge of original and replay also to be one single shared instance of a stream shared among all observers. We would have used `publish().refCount()` for this purpose, but we cannot lose the replay effect that `replayed` contains, hence it's `replay(1).refCount()`, not `publish().refCount()`.

Comment: In fact ```share()``` is an alias for ```publish().refCount()``` in RxJava as well. [docs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#share())

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't [Distinct](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/distinct.html) cover your case? BehaviorSubject only repeats the latest element after subscription.

Comment: I don't think so, as I still do want to receive the items, I just have to know if they're repeated or not.

Comment: Filter on a set you're storing outside then.

Comment: Those were the exact words I was going to say ! @MLProgrammer-CiM The Set will only conserve dstinct value from your BehaviorSubject objects.

Comment: How would that help? A bit confused on what that means.

Comment: The set only conserve distinct value, so you would not have to worry about a value being repeated. Othwerise, using Rx, distinct will filter the items that could be repeated.

Comment: I'm confused by your request too. What you want is an observable that takes all values, then enhances the data with whether they come from network or database; or you want an observable that filters values that've been received before?

Comment: The first one. (I was actually able to restructure my app to get around needing this, but I would still like to know what you guys mean, I'm still a newbie to Rx.)

Comment: That's the thing, I don't have a database or any other kind of caching system. By "cached" I just mean an old value from the BehaviorSubject. I can manipulate the item as it's received from the network (it's a subscription that calls `onNext`), but that's all as far as I can tell.

Comment: Who is your network provider? Retrofit? Volley? Future?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is something like this:

```
private final BehaviorSubject<T> fetched = BehaviorSubject.create();
private final Observable<FirstTime<T>> _fetched = fetched.lift(new Observable.Operator<FirstTime<T>, T>() {
    private AtomicReference<T> last = new AtomicReference<>();
    @Override
    public Subscriber<? super T> call(Subscriber<? super FirstTime<T>> child) {
        return new Subscriber<T>(child) {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                child.onCompleted();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                child.onError(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(T t) {
                if (!Objects.equals(t, last.getAndSet(t))) {
                    child.onNext(FirstTime.yes(t));
                } else {
                    child.onNext(FirstTime.no(t));
                }
            }
        };
    }
});

public Observable<FirstTime<T>> getObservable() {
    return _fetched;
}

public static class FirstTime<T> {
    final boolean isItTheFirstTime;
    final T value;

    public FirstTime(boolean isItTheFirstTime, T value) {
        this.isItTheFirstTime = isItTheFirstTime;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public boolean isItTheFirstTime() {
        return isItTheFirstTime;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static <T> FirstTime<T> yes(T value) {
        return new FirstTime<>(true, value);
    }

    public static <T> FirstTime<T> no(T value) {
        return new FirstTime<>(false, value);
    }
}
```

The wrapper class `FirstTime` has a boolean which can be used to see if any subscriber to the Observable has seen it before.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Store the information of BehaviorSubject objects in a data structure with a good lookup such as a Dictionnary. Each value would be a key and the value would be the number of iteration.

There so, when you look at a particulary key, if your dictionnary contains it already and its value is already at one, then you know that a value is a repeated value.

Comment: Seems a bit sloppy to have a counter over the life of the whole app :/

Comment: That is quite true, I did not take into account the life cycle of the product @D_Steve595

Comment: It should work, though. If I can't find a cleaner solution this will have to do.

Comment: As @MLProgrammer-CiM said, the set would be a good solution to conserve only distinct values. Otrherwise, I don't see any better to find repeated values with something else than a dictionnary !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you want to achieve. Probably you'd just like to have a smart source for the "latest" data and a second source which tells you when the data was refreshed?

```
    BehaviorSubject<Integer> dataSubject = BehaviorSubject.create(42); // initial value, "never empty"

    Observable<String> refreshedIndicator = dataSubject.map(data -> "Refreshed!");
    refreshedIndicator.subscribe(System.out::println);

    Observable<Integer> latestActualData = dataSubject.distinctUntilChanged();
    latestActualData.subscribe( data -> System.out.println( "Got new data: " + data));

    // simulation of background activity:
    Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .limit(100)
            .toBlocking()
            .subscribe(aLong -> dataSubject.onNext(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(2)));
```

Output:

```
Refreshed!
Got new data: 42
Refreshed!
Got new data: 0
Refreshed!
Refreshed!
Refreshed!
Got new data: 1
Refreshed!
Got new data: 0
Refreshed!
Got new data: 1
```